# How to find duplicate filenames in a directory in unix

Tags: perl, shell, unix

Below are the few files in my directory.

```
**$pwd
/opt/offline/**

1  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  40513 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER8047_07082014100213_processed
2  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  32335 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER8204_07082014100217_processed
3  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  20126 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER8047_07082014100221_processed
4  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 205175 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER7027_07082014100225_locked
5  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15776 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER7020_07082014100229_locked
6  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Aug  7 10:02 TN_DAY0OFFER7020_07082014100233_locked
```

Now 1st & 3rd files are having same name (not considering the timestamp) similarly 5th & 6th files have the same name.
Now I want to fetch the duplicate file (ie 3rd & 6th) and append it in the 1st & 5th respectively so that there would be no duplicate file and data loss...(preferably using perl or shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Perl script that does what you want. It finds files in the current directory beginning with "TN" and builds a hash of arrays, grouping together the files with similar names. It then goes through the hash and concatenates the files, removing the old files.

Needless to say, **make a backup** of your original files before using this script!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %merges;
for my $file (glob "TN*") {
    if ($file =~ /(.*)_\d+_(.*)/) {
        push @{$merges{"$1$2"}}, "'$file'";
    }
}

for (keys %merges) {
    my @files = @{$merges{$_}}; 
    my $target = shift @files;  
    if (@files) {
        print "concatenating @files to $target\n";
        `cat @files >> $target && rm @files`;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `my @parts` and then not using it. Poor OP will have that line now for eternity! `:P`

Comment: @jaypal thanks for spotting that, originally I was `split`ting the file name on /_/ but I changed my mind.

Comment: @TomFenech No worries, I kinda figured. `:)` I'm sure your answer would have got more traction if you had used more perlish way of concatenating files and deleting them but `TIMTOWDI` I guess...

Comment: @jaypal the thought did cross my mind but I came to the conclusion that on a Unix-based system, `cat` and `rm` are already pretty good at doing those jobs! Never mind...

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash 4.0.

```
#!/bin/bash

error_exit() {
    echo "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || error_exit "Script requires Bash 4.0."

[[ -z $1 || ! -d $1 ]] && error_exit "Directory not specified or doesn't exist: $1"

pushd "$1" || error_exit "Unable to change directory to $1."

declare -A MAP

shopt -s nullglob

for F in *_*_*_*; do
    [[ -f $F ]] || continue
    IFS=_ read -ra A B C D __ <<< "$F"
    BASE=${MAP["$A|$B|$D"]}
    if [[ -n $BASE ]]; then
        cat "$F" >> "$BASE"
        rm -f -- "$F"
    else
        MAP["$A|$B|$D"]=$F
    fi
done
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh dir
```

**Note:** Test it with copied files first if you don't want your files deleted or altered the wrong way.

```
cp -a dir /tmp/dir.copy
bash script.sh /tmp/dir.copy
```

When it comes to manipulation of files, the shell more appropriate. It could also work with `awk` but `awk` still relies on `/bin/sh` and sanitation of arguments is difficult or hacky sometimes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but it is not supporting BASH 4.0....:( Can you please make it little bit simple as this much complexity is not required for us.

Comment: @user3916993 How about Ruby?

Comment: Nope...I need it in Shell/Perl...

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Glob;
my $dir = $ARGV[0];
die "No argument was passed." if not defined $dir;
die "Argument is not a directory: $dir" if not -d $dir;
chdir "$dir" or die "Unable to change directory to $dir.";
my @files = <*_*_*_*>;
my $map = {};
foreach my $f (@files) {
    next if not -f $f;
    my ($a, $b, $c, $d) = split(/_/, $f);
    my $key = "$a|$b|$d";
    my $base = $map->{$key};
    if (defined $base) {
        open(A, '>>', $base) or die "Unable to open file $base for reading.";
        open(B, '<', $f) or die "Unable to open file $f for reading.";
        while (my $line = <B>) {
            print A $line;
        }
        close(A);
        close(B);
        unlink $f;
    }
    $map->{$key} = $f;
}
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some hammers cracking nuts, here....

```
#! /bin/sh -
# Concatenate files sharing a common prefix (before '_').
# The files are concatenated to a file named by the prefix.

curr=XXX

ls *_* | sort | while read fn
do
    pfx=`expr $fn : '\([^_]*\).*'`
    if test $pfx = $curr; then
        # another in this group of files, sharing a prefix
        cat $fn >> $pfx
    else
        # new group of files with prefix $pfx
        cp $fn $pfx
        curr=$pfx
    fi
done
```

That doesn't do *precisely* what you asked, but it seems to match what you want (and it doesn't involve `*shudder*` Perl).